# Vite React child component broken tailwindcss / manual changes in html code don't appear in the browser

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

***I'm still a  beginner so the errors may seem pretty obvious to yall***
The code was working just fine then suddenly it became broken.

## **[Github Repo](https://github.com/SetroZ/plshelp.git)**

in the Grid.tsx file i am applying some tailwind classes
none of which works.

```
export const Grid = ({ type, label }: GridProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`rounded-full text-center  ${Style[type]}    box-border h-16 aspect-square `}
      key={label}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Another problem in App.tsx
`<div className="grid mt-5 gap-x-5 gap-y-4 grid-cols-4 grid-rows-5 h-full   ">`
These styles also don't work.

but somehow the tailwindcss classes in other lines work

And finally when manually editing the index.html file,the changes don't appear in the browser.

desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vawb.png)

current output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi8Sh.png)

I tried restarting vite, reinstalling tailwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a separate npm task `watch` to run Tailwind CLI, import the `input.css` file in your app code. This will compile the CSS alongside your JavaScript and also will give you auto-reloading on file changes.

For example, in `src/main.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./css/input.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```